# Break lines in html column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have text in a table as follows:

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap">Some value:Another Value; Person-1:Person2</td>
```

The problem I have is that this `Some value:Another Value; Person-1:Person2` is displayed as a single line inside the column. How could I break-line it on `;`? So it is still in the same row/column but as 2 lines in the column?

Comment: just add <br> tag surely?

Comment: The problem is underspecified. There is large number of ways to break a line in HTML or in CSS, and many of the ways are so trivial (to anyone knowing basics of HTML) so the question arises whether this is all there is in the problem, really.

Comment: “In html column” is actually irrelevant here; what matters is that you have used `white-space: nowrap` and now wish to force (or just allow?) line breaks at some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<br />` to create explicit line breaks:

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap">Some value:Another Value;<br />Person-1:Person2</td>
```

Comment: Didn't knew you answered as well, `br` will be useless here, when you will resize the viewport, the string will overflow .. so in some ways, the thing what OP is trying to do is weird

Comment: If the line doesn't fit, that's a different issue. This is just how to force the two strings to be on separate lines within a table cell.

Comment: IF he wants a break after a specific character else the strings will be autowrapped anyways, but his requirements are weird.

Answer (score 4):

What about list item tag?

I think you should go for it.

Comment: This suggestion is what I actually liked

Comment: Is there a way to add this list but without the bullets etc?

Comment: add css list-style-type :none;

Answer (score -1):

This should work as a solution

```
<td>
    <span style="white-space: nowrap">Some value:Another Value;</span>
    <span style="word-break:break-all;">Person-1:Person2</span>
</td>
```